# after compiling node.js from source atom fails to load from command line only

Tags: command-line, node.js, atom

```
drupal@drupal-pc:~$ sudo find / -type f -name "libnode.so"
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Keine Berechtigung
/opt/atom/libnode.so
drupal@drupal-pc:~$ atom
atom: error while loading shared libraries: libnode.so: cannot open shared      
object file: No such file or directory
```

Since myself compiled node js from github, yesterday. atom doesn't launch atom from commandline altough the missing file is on board  In addition atom runs perfectly, when launched from the launcher icon. Any ideas!

Comment: Did [my answer below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327068/after-compiling-node-js-from-source-atom-fails-to-load-from-command-line-only/327073#327073) help you? Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

If it cannot find the library but it's there then maybe it doesn't search in the right place. Adding something like this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/atom"
```

to you .profile or .bashrc might help here but the problem may be different.

Or maybe you should have the atom's path switched with your new node's path in you PATH environment variable.

It all depends on where you installed new Node, if you removed old Node and how etc. Here is [my tutorial](https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a) on how to install Node from sources and how to deal with the paths. Maybe you can compare it to the way you built and installed Node yourself.

Comment: This produce an other errorr. Cant  remember right now. But the problem presists. I'll add the errorr message tomorrow.

Comment: This is the error your solution is producing.

atom: error while loading shared libraries: libnode.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64